# Show image on mouse over for elements of a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of my favourite movies. I would like to display the poster of the movie when the user hovers over the name of the movie. I managed to do it for one element:

```
<body>
    <h2> My Top 10 Movies </h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>01</td>
            <td onmouseover="imageAppear()" onmouseout="imageDisappear()">Drive<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Drive2011Poster.jpg" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"/></td>
            <td>Nicolas Winding Refn</td>
            <td>2011</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
    function imageAppear() { 
    document.getElementById('place-holder-1').style.visibility = "visible";}

    function imageDisappear() { 
    document.getElementById('place-holder-1').style.visibility = "hidden";}

    </script>
</body>
```

My question is, how can I do the same for multiple items without writing X functions for each of my movie? I tried using classes, but it does not seem to work (and even if it does, it would show all the pictures when the user hovers over any of the titles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the id of the element as a parameter of your function:

```
    <script>
    function imageAppear(id) { 
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";}

    function imageDisappear(id) { 
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";}

    </script>
```

And in your table call it:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>01</td>
            <td onmouseover="imageAppear('place-holder-1')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('place-holder-1')">Drive<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Drive2011Poster.jpg" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"/></td>
            <td>Nicolas Winding Refn</td>
            <td>2011</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery (since you're writting your solution with JS I think it would be ok for you)

You could something like :

```
<body>
 <h2> My Top 10 Movies </h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>01</td>
            <td>Drive<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Drive2011Poster.jpg" id="place-holder-1" style="zindex: 100; position: absolute; display: none;"/></td>
            <td>Nicolas Winding Refn</td>
            <td>2011</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('tr td:nth-child(2)').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).find('img').show();
        });
        $('tr td:nth-child(2)').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find('img').hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td class="imageHover"></td>
        <td>Nicolas Winding Refn</td>
        <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td class="imageHover img1"></td>
        <td>Nicolas Winding Refn</td>
        <td>2012</td>
    </tr>
```

**CSS**

```
  .imageHover:hover{
    background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Drive2011Poster.jpg');
}

.img1:hover{

    background:url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhKewtNASQ-YZiNOWGXach389U4ZvUiVUyvrxLCAt0OQcR3Evh');
}
.imageHover{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.imageHover:before{
    content:'Drive';
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9N3U/4/)

Comment: Hi Kawinesh, unless I am missing something your solution only works if the same poster has to be displayed for each entry, am I wrong? I need to be able to display different images for each of my entry.

Comment: @AnnoysParrot just check the demo now.Have Diff classes and change the background url.